# Simultaneous OleDbDataAdapter.Fill Calls on Separate Threads?

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, oledbdataadapter

First timer here, so go easy on me.  Is it theoretically possible to execute two OleDBDataAdapter.Fill calls on separate threads simultaneously - or is that fundamentally flawed?

Consider a form with 2 buttons and 2 datagridviews.  Each button click launches a worker thread using an Async \ Await \ Task.Run pattern that calls a method to return a populated datatable and assigns it to one of the datagridviews.  The .Fill in the first thread takes 30 seconds to complete.  The .Fill in the second thread takes 1 second to complete.  When launched individually, both buttons work as expected.

However, if I launch the first worker thread (30 seconds to Fill), then launch the second thread (1 second Fill), the second DataGridView is not populated until the first .Fill call completes.  I would expect the second datagridview to populate in 1 second, and the first datagridview to populate ~30 seconds later.

I have duplicated this issue in my sample code with both the OleDBDataAdapter and the SqlDataAdapter.  If I replace the long running query with a simple Thread.Sleep(30000), the second datagridview is populated right away.  This leads me to be believe that it is not an issue with my design pattern, rather something specific to issuing the .Fill calls simultaneously.

```
Private Async Sub UltraButton1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles UltraButton1.Click

    Dim Args As New GetDataArguments
    Args.ConnectionString = "some connection string"
    Args.Query = "SELECT LongRunningQuery from Table"

    Dim DT As DataTable = Await Task.Run(Function() FillDataTable(Args))
    If DataGridView1.DataSource Is Nothing Then
        DataGridView1.DataSource = DT
    Else
        CType(DataGridView1.DataSource, DataTable).Merge(DT)
    End If

End Sub

Function FillDataTable(Args As GetDataArguments) As DataTable

    Dim DS As New DataTable

    Using Connection As New OleDbConnection(Args.ConnectionString)
        Using DBCommand As New OleDbCommand(Args.Query, Connection)
            Using DataAdapter As New OleDbDataAdapter(DBCommand)
                DataAdapter.Fill(DS)
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using

    Return DS

End Function

Private Async Sub UltraButton2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles UltraButton2.Click

    Dim DS As DataTable = Await Task.Run(Function() LoadSecondDGV("1234"))
    DataGridView2.DataSource = DS

End Sub

Function LoadSecondDGV(pnum As String) As DataTable

    Dim DX As New DataTable

    Using xConn As New OleDbConnection("some connection string")
        Using DataAdapter As New OleDbDataAdapter("Select name from products where PNUM = """ & pnum & """", xConn)
            DataAdapter.Fill(DX)
        End Using
    End Using

    Return DX

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

This depends on what the data source is. Some data sources (like Excel) will only allow one connection at a time. Other data sources (like Access) will allow multiple connections, but actually fulfill the results in serial, such that you don't gain anything. Other data sources, like Sql Server, will allow the true parallel activity that you're looking for.

In this case, you mention that you also tried with an SqlDataAdapter, which indicates to me that you're talking to Sql Server, and this should be possible. What's probably going on here is that your first query is *locking* some of the data you need for the second query. You can get past this by changing your [transaction isolation level](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx) or through careful use of the `with (nolock)` hint (the former option is strongly preferred).

One other thing to keep in mind is that this can only work if you're using a separate connection for each query, or if you've specifically enabled the Multiple Active Result Sets feature. It looks like you're using separate connection objects here, so you should be fine, but it's still something I thought was worth bringing up.

Finally, I need to comment on your `FillDataTable()` method. This method requires you to provide a completed Sql string, which practically forces you to write code that will be horribly vulnerable to sql injection attacks. Continuing to use the method as shown practically guarantees your app will get hacked, probably sooner rather than later. You need to modify this method so that it encourages you to use parameterized queries.

Comment: I am actually using an Access database, but I did simulate the test against SQL Server with the exact same behavior.  I queried completely unrelated tables in both cases to ensure that I was not blocking myself.  I appreciate the sql injection warning - this is just some quick and dirty PoC winforms code.  Any other thoughts?  I realize that I do not have execution ready code here given the nature of connection strings and such, but I am very curious to know if anyone can reproduce the issue.

Comment: Actually, the issue remains if I query two completely separate unrelated Access databases in each thread.  That has to mean that something innate to the DataAdapter objects is getting shared across threads, no?

Comment: @rSquared I just realized you're using `async` to do this. It's important to understand the `async` does **not** use multiple threads. It allows things to run out of order _in the same thread_. It gives the _appearance_ of parallelism, and it does very often make (**much**) more efficient use of your cpu or single thread, but it's not actually parallel. If you have something that blocks, like a database call, you're still going to see one call finish, and then the other.

Comment: I'll admit to this being my first time using Async and Task.Run, but I see multiple worker threads spawned in the Threads window.  Also, if I use the TracePoints feature in both the FillDataTable and LoadSecondDGV routine - they are identified as running on separate threads.  Am I misunderstanding what I am looking at?